# selecting the last child of the last child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to give a border to the last child li in the last child UL

```
.products-grid.columns7 ul:last-child li.item.boxed:last-child { border-left: #d9d9d9 1px solid; }
```

Does not seem to work.

doing:

```
.products-grid.columns7 li.item.boxed:last-child { border-left: #d9d9d9 1px solid; }
```

Does work, however it selects all of the last li

Comment: Post your markup as well.

Comment: what's your HTML markup?

Answer (score 3):

Since `.products-grid.columns7 li.item.boxed:last-child` is working as you mentioned, my best guess is that the `ul` is **not the last child** of its parent.

Therefore `ul:last-child` won't match the last `ul`.

Try using [`ul:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) instead:

```css
.products-grid.columns7 ul:last-of-type li.item.boxed:last-child {
    border-left: #d9d9d9 1px solid;
}
```

> **[6.6.5.9. :last-of-type pseudo-class](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors3/#last-of-type-pseudo)**
>
> The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last
>   **sibling of its type** in the list of children of its parent element.

Comment: could be too : `.products-grid.columns7:last-child li.item.boxed:last-child` :)

Comment: @GCyrillus This is just a speculation :)

Answer (score 0):

assuming this is a list within a list here is what you can do.

```
ul>li:last-child>ul>li:last-child {
color:red;
}
```

see example here : http://jsfiddle.net/0rfo90x7/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little modified css for you...

CSS

```
<style>
    .products-grid.columns7 ul:last-of-type li.item.boxed:last-child {
        border-left: red 20px solid;
        display: block;/* or inline-block*/
    }
</style>
```